# How to not include everything from Foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation

I installed Foundation on my Rails-powered site in order to use  the orbit and modal component via `rails g foundation:install` And only the CSS needed/associated with those two are what I want to get included. Because all of Foundation's styles got included and my styles got overridden. How do I do that?

Comment: @use foundation.scss-change the imports. include the ones you need

Comment: Already tried that but foundation's including everything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Gem, you can just include the css files that you need in the app/assets/stylesheets folder. The Rails asset pipeline will automatically include those css files for you.